# Pathfinder druid animal companions damage

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I need some clarification. Lets say we have a ***Cat, Big***

#### Starting Statistics

Size Medium; Speed 40 ft.; AC +1 natural armor; Attack bite (1d6), 2 claws (1d4); Ability Scores Str 13, Dex 17, Con 13, Int 2, Wis 15, Cha 10; Special Attacks rake (1d4); Special Qualities low-light vision, scent.

So does the pet's attacks look something like this (lets say we have +1 BAB)?

> Attack bite 1d6+1, 2 claws 1d4+1

or

> Attack bite 1d6+1, 1 claw 1d4+1, 1 claw 1d4+1

or

> Attack bite 1d6+1, 1 claw 1d4+1, 1 claw 1d4 (because you cant get +1 on bot h the claws?)

or

> Attack bite 1d6+1

or

> 2 claws 1d4+1

(this is all the ways I think it can be ATM, so I have no idea)

And does it attack both attacks on the same round or is it just one of them?

How does it work? How do you calculate your animal companion's damage?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! Just wanted to say hi, and suggest you take a look at the [Tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about/) when you get a chance. And when you get 20 rep, feel free to join us in the [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)!

Answer (score 4):

You are allowed all three attacks without any penalty since they are primary attacks. See the above response he explains that very well.

According to the base stats of your cat, big, your attack would be as follows:

first: bite (1d6)    attack roll: 1d20 (+1 BAB; +1 for your strength mod)
damage roll: 1d6 (+1 for your strength mod)

second: claw (1d4)    attack roll: 1d20 (+1 BAB; +1 for your strength mod)
damage roll: 1d4 (+1 for your strength mod)

third: claw (1d4)    attack roll: 1d20 (+1 BAB; +1 for your strength mod)
damage roll: 1d6 (+1 for your strength mod)

At [level 9](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions#TOC-Multiattack) your animal companion receives the Multiattack feat, however the RAW as stated above leads me to believe that your particular companion ***would not receive an extra bite.***

"If it **does not have the requisite three or more natural attacks,** the animal companion instead gains a second attack with its primary natural weapon, albeit at a –5 penalty"

The fact is that a big cat **does** have three natural attacks (primary attacks are a type of natural attack), so they should not be given an extra bite.

Comment: Caunion, unfortunately, we don't really like answers that reference other answers. Your answer should stand alone. Please edit it to be complete.

Comment: Where did you get your quote from the Multiattack feat? My copy of the bestiary doesn't say that, nor does the d20pfsrd.com entry. ( http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/multiattack-combat ) By the version of the feat I have, the 3 attacks is simply a prerequisite, so without them it couldn't take or use the feat at all.

Comment: I think the multiattack feat there is just a way to give the animal companion a second at attack at BAB +6 like other classes. By your logic a multiattack is useless to a cat, and the line you quoted is even more useless. Besides "three or more natural attacks" might mean three or more types such as claw, bite and tail. The cat only has claw and bite.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to determine your attack scores, the first table you check is this.

[Natural Attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Natural-Attacks). Here it says that claws and a bite is primary. Therefore they are all made at full base attack bonus, +2 for all and full strength damage. One bite and two claws. 1d6+1, 1d4+1,1d4+1.

For referance check out a big cat [example](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/cat-great/lion). This lion can make all his attacks at full BAB and your cat is the same. Claws and Bite are primary weapons.

At 8th level your companion gains Multiattack. This normally reduces penalty on secondary attacks like tail or tentacle but since your animal does not have this kind of attack, it will grant a bite attack at -5 Penalty.

> If it does not have the requisite three or more natural attacks, the
>   animal companion instead gains a second attack with its primary
>   natural weapon, albeit at a –5 penalty

Comment: a quick one, so i get no penaltys befor 8th level? and after i get rake+claw+claw+rake+bite+rake+bite(last bite at -5)? and on normal attack without rake its claw+claw+bite+bite(last bite at -5)?

Comment: Nope. Keep in mind that rake can only be used while grappling. If your animal gains pounce ability, rake can also be used during charge.

Comment: As Caunion comments in his answer, RAW the cat does *not* get a second bite. (Multiattack doesn't help it...but they only get the extra attack if they don't have at least three attacks already.)

Comment: Where did you get your quote from the Multiattack feat? My copy of the bestiary doesn't say that, nor does the d20pfsrd.com entry. ( http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/multiattack-combat ) By the version of the feat I have, the 3 attacks is simply a prerequisite, so without them it couldn't take or use the feat at all.

Comment: The quote isnt from multiattack feat, it's from animal companion part. Source is here; http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions#TOC-Multiattack